# How can I change product category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I need some code, which change product category in woocommerce, if the date stored in ACF field of product is gone. Each product has ACF field called "start_date".

I tried to create function in function.php file.

```
<?php 

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'your_activation');
add_action('your_daily_event', 'rub_change_categories');

function your_activation() {
  $first_time = time(); 
  $recurrence = 'daily';    
  wp_schedule_event($first_time, $recurrence, 'your_daily_event');
}

function rub_change_categories(){
$myproducts = get_posts( array(   
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'product_cat' => 'New' 
    ));

foreach ($myproducts as $product) {
$key = 'start_date'; //name of ACF field
$start = get_post_meta($product->ID, $key, true); // start date

$todays_date = date('Ymd'); // get current date

if ($start < $todays_date) {

    wp_set_object_terms($product->ID, 'Old', product_cat');
    //change category to "Old"           

        }
    }
}


?>
```

I tried this code, but nothing happened. I think that some problem is in function `wp_set_object_terms`, because, this code works if I use this function for changing category of the simple post. But if I used it for products and 'product_cat' nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried "update_post_meta" instead of "wp_set_object_terms"?

Comment: @MrEbabi yes, but it is the same problem.